# Issues with Responsiveness and Custom Styling in "Related Products" Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2.4

[MyView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyR5K.png)Title: Issues with Responsiveness and Custom Styling in "Related Products" Block in Magento 2

Body:

Hello community,

I'm currently facing challenges regarding both responsiveness and custom styling in the "Related Products" block on my Magento 2 store. I'm using the free Magefan Auto Related Products extension and have attempted to modify the list.phtml templates, but I'm struggling to achieve an appropriate responsive view. Specifically, I'm trying to display two columns of two products in the mobile view.

In addition, I'm attempting to customize the appearance of the block and change the way related product information is displayed. However, I'm having difficulty identifying the specific template controlling these aspects.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have experience with the Magefan Auto Related Products extension? Any suggestions on which Magento template files might be affecting these issues or how to achieve both responsive design and customization of the "Related Products" block appearance?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or help you can provide!